# Should I edit a pure abusive/offensive post

Tags: discussion, edits, offensive, abuse

If some frustrated user posts an offensive sentence (not swearing in a valid answer, just pure hate & swearing & insulting everyone), should I:

- (Downvote,) flag, and wait
- Edit to some "abusive, please delete" sentence, (downvote,) flag, and wait

Should we use deletion features to delete the post without the mods involved or doing that is reserved for technically wrong posts?

Is editing the post to avoid that someone sees that in the meantime (mods may be busy deleting other offensive posts) a problem, or am I just wasting my & everyone else time?

Comment: downvote and vote to delete is likely faster route than flag... (I'd flag it anyway as offensive)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov doing so doesn't put the mods in the loop, so the user can start again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> (downvote,) flag, and wait

That's the one.

> edit to some "abusive, please delete" sentence, (downvote,) flag, and wait

DONT do this. In this way,

1. You'll be preventing other users from flagging the post quickly as the edit will have hidden the original post. Now the user will have to check the revisions and then see the original post.
2. (In the case of spam edits only) You'll be interfering with the audit mechanism. Audits are picked from spam flagged posts and if you've edited it into non spam, then there's a chance that you're giving away a robo-reviewer a very helpful hint.
3. You'll be given the abusive poster a golden chance to rollback the edit and invalidate all the flags on their post.

Related: [Should spam posts be edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110030/should-spam-posts-be-edited/110031#110031)

> Should we use deletion features to delete the post without the mods involved or doing that is reserved for technically wrong posts ?

You *can* use deletion, but that is not helpful. Using flags are way more helpful, because:

1. It's brought to the top of the moderator queue.
2. Enough spam/rude flags also influence heavily towards an answer ban.
3. 6 flag spam/rude (or 1 mod flag spam/rude) would feed them into the SpamRam which would prevent them from creating more accounts to post.
4. It'd throw an insta penalty of 100 rep, depriving them of any privilege they'd have got (assuming that they are <100 rep).

> Is editing the post to avoid that someone sees that in the meantime (mods may be busy deleting other offensive posts) a problem, or am I just wasting my & everyone else time ?

Yes, you're wasting your time and everyone else's time. Add a red flag. If it doesn't accumulate more flags, then you can ask in a chatroom for help. The [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) is a nice place to start.