# Rude flag dismissed on comment saying user "doesn't seem to be able to develop basic Java code"

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, specific-answer, behavior, rude-or-abusive

I flagged the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49129938/can-jmeter-mock-http-request/49130518#49130518) as rude because of the line:

> Especially for user7294900 who doesn't seem to be able to develop basic Java code:

It violates the first and third rules of [be nice model](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice):

> Your tone should match the way you'd talk in person with someone you respect and whom you want to respect you.
>
> Focus on the post, not the person. That includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to posts

Obviously it focus on person and rude,
Why was my flag  [declined](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/7294900)?

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

I don't necessary want to remove the answer, just the rude comment

Comment: I agree. This is common. Today I flagged ""Do yourself and the [java] community a favor and do find out why LinkedList is so bad" - also declined. *There is a way to send your message without being rude. A bad question is no excuse.*

Comment: I know it's hard when you're directly attacked, but when you can edit and remove that attack and leave the otherwise good answer, I don't see why  the answer needs to be deleted due to the flag.

Comment: @AndrewT. Then does a mod not have the power to edit the post & mark the flag as helpful?

Comment: @jpp, the comment you flagged has nothing on what 7294900 is reporting here. And better not to involve the mods unless it's really necessary. I think that that flag shouldn't have been declined, but that  editing that post first was probably a better move.

Comment: @Andrew T. I don't necessary want to remove the answer, just the rude comment

Comment: You have 10k rep. You can edit it yourself, right?

Comment: Additional context in the deleted comments [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smAD4.png). While the answerer's behavior isn't excusable, this whole thing does remind me of why answerers are burning out and lashing out. In my experience, asking someone to "give an example" is one of the last things you should ever do on SO, especially after they've painstakingly put together an expository answer with a wealth of links to get you started.

Comment: @Andrew T. yes, but it was a part of a serial rude comments

Comment: Personally, I think that the first step edit it yourself (well, I edited it myself now). If the answerer rolls it back, then you involve the mods. Or you roll it back again and an auto-flag is raised.

Comment: Now I can see the situation after BoltClock's comment. I can agree that the declining it was quite unexpected. But still, you're asking mod to edit and remove it while you can do it yourself?

Comment: As for the flag, I'm very puzzled by the reason used for declining your flag. Clearly there was overwhelming evidence that the answerer was being rude. If the moderator had wanted to send a message that you could have edited the answer yourself, they should have picked "flags should only be used for content that requires moderator intervention" or a custom reason stating it plainly. Even so, at worst, I would have disputed the flag. That third way out is given to us for red flags for a reason.

Comment: So, in the sense that every moderator who runs agrees to be culpable for their actions, who was it and what was their reasoning?

Comment: @TravisJ, I don't think we should expect public responses from moderators for *every* questioned decision. Some decisions are [unpopular](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365889/9209546), others [popular](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365950/9209546), the end result is a lot of unnecessary polarizing. When, in fact, nothing is black & white, the input falls somewhere on a sliding scale of acceptability.

Comment: @jpp generally when a moderator decision does not make sense to the community at large, the moderator who made the decision is expected to own up to it on meta and explain their reasoning. They don't _have_ to, but I have yet to see a case where they did not. Polarizing discussions happen on meta... _all the time_, and that is in no way a bad thing. Without differing opinions and polarizing debates, we would all agree, then we would never get anything done.

Comment: @TinyGiant, Fair enough. My point is this: you are asking a moderator to defend their decision. That's an entirely reasonable request. What you *very rarely find* is a complete response, which would be: "These were the positives, these were the negatives. We weighted it all up and came to this conclusion." It's human nature, I wish measured responses were valued more in general (not just on SO). But when you ask someone to defend and they respond, *they will defend*. It's a subtle difference, and maybe it's just terminology, but I'd ask for the *issues that were considered* in the decision.

Comment: @jpp I'm trying to figure out how your last comment coalesces with your previous comment. To me they both seem like completely different points, but it reads as you trying to explain your previous point, which you instead proceed to contradict.

Comment: @TinyGiant, Maybe I didn't explain my previous comment properly. When I say, "I don't think we should expect public responses from moderators for every questioned decision," I mean we should *not* ask "Why did you decline?" We *should* ask, "What factors did you consider?" These can have very different responses, in my opinion.

Comment: @jpp plus, LinkedList is by no means bad. True, it only has very narrow use cases but it is a suitable single threaded double ended queue implementation with reasonable performance and WELL tested ^^

Comment: @yeoman, I'm the one who flagged the comment [for style, not content], not the one who wrote it :). Of course, it was declined.

Comment: @jpp hence, the plus, ... leading into the comment ^^ I had, of course, only realized that just after the fact, and added the plus, ... with an edit.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Just edit it out and leave a joyful edit comment, something like

> *My Basic is better than my Java but I soon hope to add Script*

or anything else that de-escalates.

If that gets rolled-back or causes backlash you can at least show you've done everything to resolve the issue in a constructive way. That is the first moment to consider a mod-flag.

And when you flag use a custom flag to explain what is going on / wrong. Using a rude flag on a post that *also* has value, is bound to be declined as red flags that get marked helpful do carry a -100 rep penalty. I'm not sure if that is in order here for something that can still be solved in a different way.

From  [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) *Oh, and bring your sense of humor*

Comment: Answer already edited, can the decline flag be roll backed?

Comment: I have no idea what that comment entails. Are you addressing me @user7294900

Comment: spot on, moderators have enough work removing rude comments. If you can edit it out, do it!

Comment: @rene Can you please clarify what you mean by "red flags to get marked helpful do carry a -100 rep penalty?" I didn't quite understand it. Thanks!

Comment: @ndmeiri If a "Spam" or a "Rude/Abusive" flag on a question or answer (not on comments) is validated by a mod, or if the post gets 6 such flags, the user who posted it loses 100 rep, along with some backend stuff to try to train the system to block the spam sooner (if flagged spam) and I believe there's some sort of network restriction as well.

Comment: @Kendra I did not know that. Is that the case across all (or at least most) Exchanges? Maybe a better question, is there somewhere that lays out all these types of effects?

Comment: @LordFarquaad I think you'll find pretty much all the info [on Meta SE.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor) As far as I'm aware, this works 100% the same regardless of site.

Comment: @Kendra correct, IIRC spam flags send the IP address to SpamRam so the ip address gets blocked. On rude/abusive flags that specific step is not executed.

Comment: I honestly couldn't completely remember that step, thanks @rene

Comment: @ rene and @Kendra: Red flags can be marked helpful by a mod with no effect. In fact, I don't think manually deleting a red-flagged post causes the penalty to kick in, although there aren't many test cases.

Answer (score 9):

Moderators have a lot on their plates with actions that only them can do. If this was on a comment, that would be different (and the moderator action would be easier: delete comment, done). The moderator should probably have edited that out, but the limit between non-constructive and rude is sometimes vague.

Stackoverflow has this progressive privilege system, use it.

If the answer is posted from a throwaway/hacked account to promote some dumb tool or insulting the whole world, *just flag it* (I asked about that [Should I edit a pure abusive/offensive post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359869/should-i-edit-a-pure-abusive-offensive-post), and the answer is: don't edit, just flag to make moderation work easier).

Else, if the post can be easily salvaged (which seems to be the case), editing the offending line allows to keep technical value of the answer, so edit it out or if you don't have enough privileges, suggest that edit. The edit queue will end the job.

I might add that this is a very mature behaviour to just edit the post and leave it be (maybe with a polite comment explaining the situation). The answerer may have had a bad day... As always, don't take it personally, which you didn't, since no one downvoted the answer, which looks good.

Comment: "Just edit the post and leave it be." In other words (mine): let go of wanting to see someone reprimanded for their actions. That's pretty much at the heart of a lot of these cases, people don't want to erase the evidence because they want to see if punishment is a possibility.

Comment: I agree with this action for posts. But what about comments? If a rude/abusive comment is also funny, should I upvote or flag? This isn't a joke. *Most* of my accepted rude/abusive flagged comments are highly upvoted.

Comment: @Gimby yes, let go. If the guy persists, maybe flag, with several posts attached (history is kept). I must admit I saw snarky comments a lot, but almost never in otherwise okay answers.

Comment: @jpp: I've been there too. It's tempting to create a good joke at OP expense. It really depends on who's rude first. A bozo posting a screenshot (with flash and all) of his code can be mocked a bit (last time I asked OP to fax us the code instead :)). An honest mistake shouldn't be laughed at, or gently, with smileys and all. Make fun _with_ OP not _of_ OP. Well, that's how I see it.